# Unable to understand some part of this snippet?

Tags: c

I have this example program from a book, in this piece of code there is a line 
`++frequency[responses[RESPOSE_SIZE]];`. I am unable to understand how we are incrementing array base address? may be i am a fool? but still i dont see any logic there...please some one help me out ....thanks!

```
    int main()
    {
          int answer, rating;

           int frequency[FREQUENCY_SIZE] = {5};

           int responses[RESPOSE_SIZE] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,

                1,6,3,8,6,10,3,8,2,7,6,5,7,6,8,6,7,5,6,6, 

                5,6,7,5,6,4,8,6,8,10};

       for(answer = 0; answer<RESPOSE_SIZE; answer++)
       {

          ++frequency[responses[RESPOSE_SIZE]];
       }

       printf( "%s%17s\n", "Rating", "Frequency" );

       for(rating=1; rating<FREQUENCY_SIZE; rating++)
       {
          printf( "%6d%17d\n", rating, frequency[ rating ] );

       }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: responses[RESPOSE_SIZE] is **out** of valid memory space. That code seems bogus.

Comment: You couldn't possibly come up with a less descriptive and less helpful title.

Answer (score 3):

`++frequency[responses[RESPOSE_SIZE]]` does not mean that the base address of the array is incremented.

It means the item in the array `frequency` from position `responses[RESPONSE_SIZE]`is incremented. The construct `responses[RESPONSE_SIZE]` is the item in the array `responses` from position `RESPONSE_SIZE`.

Comment: Thanks my friend, it means it will collect the element from array and then it will increment it...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` indexing operator has a higher precedence than the `++` prefix increment operator. So the prefix increment operation is applied to the array element found after indexing, not to the array base address.

Comment: Buff, I am sorry but i understand that ++(frequency[responses[RESPOSE_SIZE]]) first it will access the element from frequency array and increment. But in that case it could have been better to use post increment why pre increment...sorry my friend ...but little confuse

Comment: For that particular line, post increment would work just as well.  So would `frequency[responses[RESPOSE_SIZE]] += 1;`.  As to why the person who wrote the code preferred one over the other, you'll have to ask him/her.  I don't see why post-increment would be any more (or less) readable than pre-increment here.

Comment: Actually - a more important question for the author of the code would be why they're accessing `responses[RESPOSE_SIZE]` at all.  `RESPOSE_SIZE` is an invalid index for the `responses[]` array.  I'm guessing that maybe it's supposed to be `++frequency[responses[answer]];`?